PHP does not go to another page after 'Submit' button is pressed
I'm creating a transactional website for my ICT coursework, and I am making it on Adobe Dreamweaver using PHP, Javascript, and CSS. This is my login.php and, when the 'submit' button is pressed, should take the user to the signin.php page.
Here is my login.php:
<?php 
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: ./account");
}
include('header.php'); ?>
<main class="container">
    <div class="mb-4" style="background-color: #653f97;">
    
    <!-- Login Form -->
    <div class="p-4">
        <p><span style="color:red; text-align: center;"><?php
            if(!empty($_SESSION["signinError"])){
            echo $_SESSION["signinError"]; }?></span></p>
        <form action="./signin" method="post" id="signin">
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameInput" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="usernameInput">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordInput" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="passwordInput">Password</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" />
        </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-left">
            <a href="./forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
            <p>New to Musify? <a href="./register">Register</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>

When the 'submit' button is pressed, it does not redirect to http://localhost/signin, but to http://localhost/username=(the username I submitted)&password=(the password I submitted)/. No error messages appear, nothing. It just sends me back to this login.php page and does not take me anywhere. Am I stupid and is there just an error somewhere in the code that I'm not seeing?

for reference, I have a .htaccess file (if that helps.)


oh yes i forgot to say that ive already changed that on my other computer, whoops, let me edit that now..

It might help to also post your htaccess file, since you appear to be doing stuff in there, too. The form's action is ./signin and it sounds like you want that to be handled by signin.php. Or, can you try just using the real PHP file name in the action, which should bypass htaccess

i’ve tried switching it to signin.php, but it still refuses to redirect me…

Is there any JavaScript here that might be doing some sort of "validation"?

Unrelated to your problem, and I apologize if it sounds pedantic, but generally "redirect" means something else, specifically a 301 or 302 HTTP redirect. In your case, when you click the submit button the browser is just not going to the page you want. If you are seeing a 301 or 302 in your browser tools, then you are being redirected. So to be clear, you don't want to be redirected. I say all this because when talking to other developers, including on this site, it can add confusion to the conversation.

okay! thanks for letting me know. as a high school student (and not a web developer hahaha) i just thought “redirect” meant going to another webpage thank you for the clarification!

and also, i have a js file that is basically making a ‘slideshow-gallery-thing’ for me. it does raise an error when using the ’inspect’ tool on web browser, but i don’t really think that it is relevant to the error i’m getting.

Are you running all of this through a server of some sort? XAMPP or similar?

Let's try simplifying everything. Create a brand new page, let's say test.php, and in that page only put the HTML from here. No header, footer, PHP, CSS or anything else. Then make another page called test2.php, and in that page put the PHP from here. Visit the first page in your browser, click the button, and confirm that you are getting to the second page, and that you see an array with a single key and value.

You should exit immediately after calling header() to redirect.

Look at the Network tab in Developer Tools to see what's happening when you submit the form. Either there's JavaScript overriding the form's action, or the server has a redirect that's doing this.

try replacing action="./signin" with action="/signin". May be there is a problem with relative routing.

First of all, could you please try and be a bit more precise in your observations. I really doubt that you actually land on a URL like http://localhost/username=(the username I submitted)&password=(the password I submitted)/ - I am guessing there is actually a question mark involved, and the whole thing starts with http://localhost/?username=...? Which would suggest that your form submitted using method GET, not POST.

"It just sends me back to this login.php page" - how would it be "sending you back"? The URL you said you landed on does not contain login.php, so how would it show you the content of that script again then?

im using uwamp using the server localhost.
sorry for not being precise, i couldnt see the url so i jusst got it from memory, its accurate though to what ive been seeing, also it doesnt send me back, sorry, just takes me nowhere
also i never used get, i use post and i know that
